# How to call an external web service url using apache camel

Tags: spring, apache, apache-camel

How to get data from external webservice url in apache camel 
e.g from this url
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600AmphitheatreParkway

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [http component](http://camel.apache.org/http.html). For your example :

```
    from("direct:start")
    .to("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600AmphitheatreParkway")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .to("log:logOut");
```

This route will request the web service each time a message is sent to the `direct:start` component. To use the reply, simply change `log` by the end of your road.